How to truly disable Databricks AI assistant features for a workspace?
I need to disable features where AI is used with analysing context, code found inside notebooks.
There is an option for workspace admins, Settings > Account > Advanced > Azure AI services-powered assistive features, which is already disabled. This settings can be managed from the admin console too, where it is also disabled.
However, our users have another option: Settings > User > Developer > Automatic Assistant Autocomplete which can still be enabled by the user. If enabled, typing code ivokes azuredatabricks.net/ajax-api/2.0/conversation-v2/ghost-text sending the whole code as prompt.
Is there a way to truly disable AI features, and enforce it across all settings, users?

What AI features you want to disable?

@JayashankarGS Obviously all of them. This is why the admin-level AI assistive features was disabled.


Is there a way to trully disable AI features, and enforce it across all settings, users?

AFAIK, as of now, there isn't a direct way to disable the Automatic Assistant Autocomplete features for all users at the account level.
Individual user has control to disable Automatic Assistant Autocomplete they need to disable the feature themselves in their developer settings.
As per document to disable the Automatic Assistant Autocomplete you need to do it from user settings.


To turn off autocomplete suggestions, toggle  Autocomplete as you type. When autocomplete is off, you can display autocomplete suggestions by pressing  Ctrl + Space.
To prevent  Enter  from inserting autocomplete suggestions, toggle  Enter key accepts autocomplete suggestions.




Thanks for the answer. This is therrible from security view, hope they change it soon.
